# Dynamically load Google Maps API

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I would like to load dynamically the google maps api - when I specific element exists on the current page.

When I try to use the geocoder, I get the following message:

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

So i think the maps api could not be successfully loaded, but in firebug everything looks fine (the Script gets called correct)

```
if ($('.vcard').length > 0) {

    // load google maps when vcard is present

    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
    $("head").append(s);

    // error here - unable to use google maps
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I used the Google API Loader to load the maps API only when page had finished loading. It is explained [here](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-load-the-google-maps-places-library-through-google-api-loader/comment-page-1/#comment-175489). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for pointing me into the correct direction. Already found out, that google has a example for asyncrounous loading:

```
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
      '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function addGoogleMap() {

    if ($('.vcard').length > 0) {
        loadScript();
    }
}

function initialize() {

    // get the adress
    var CurrentAddress = $('.adr').children().text();

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': CurrentAddress }, function (results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 

        console.log('success'); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your code to run *after* the script loads:

```
if ($('.vcard').length > 0) {

    // load google maps when vcard is present

    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
    s.onload = function() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    };
    $("head").append(s);
```